# Writing a method for factorial

Tags: java

I'm studying the code below in my textbook. It uses the combinations method and the factorial method to calculate the possible outcomes given n and k. My question is with the factorial method specifically the content in the for loop.

I understand everything else about the program but I don't understand  the code i <=n in the for loop in the factorial method.  What other part of the program is n referred to? I'm just not sure about the rationale behind i <= n or how the programmer comes up with that.

```
import acm.program.*;

public class combinations extends ConsoleProgram {
    public void run(){
        int n = readInt("Enter the number of objects in the set (n): ");
        int k = readInt("Enter the number to be chosen (k): ");
        println("C (" + n + ", " + k + ") = " + combinations (n, k) );

    }

    private int combinations (int n, int k){
        return factorial (n) / (factorial (k) * factorial (n-k));

    }


    private int factorial (int n){
        int result = 1; 

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
            result *= i;

        }
        return result;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`n` is a parameter of the method: because the method is declared as `int factorial(int n)`, you invoke it as (for example) `factorial(5)` to get the local variable `n` set to `5`. (In formal terms, `n` is the *parameter* and `5` is the *argument*, though usually people don't bother to distinguish those two terms.)

Comment: very interesting. Thanks! In the method private int combinations(int n, int k) the value for n and k come from the number the users enters from the prompt at the beginning of the program. IS my understand correct?

Comment: @JessicaM.: That happens to be the case, yes; but you can also just write `combinations(5, 3)`, or `combinations(n * n, k)`, or anything else. The variables named `n` and `k` in the `combinations` method are completely independent of the variables named `n` and `k` in the `run` method. (Obviously from the programmer's perspective there are good reasons that these variable-names match, but from the compiler's perspective it doesn't matter.)

Comment: I have another quick question. If the values for each method are separate from each other how does the combinations method know n = 2  and k = 2 and not the other way around?

Comment: Sorry trying to type on a tablet.  I was trying to type for example if  n = 5 and k = 2

Comment: @JessicaM.: Because `run` calls `combinations (n, k)`, which means that `run` is passing in its `n` variable as the first argument (which corresponds to `combinations`' first parameter, also named `n`) and its `k` variable as the second argument (which corresponds to `combinations`' second parameter, also named `k`).

Answer (score 2):

So, a bit of math.  Typically, when one deals with a mathematical expression, math conventions are frequently used.  *n* is typically referred to some upper ceiling value that the method should refer to.

Essentially, the function definition for a factorial is this.

```
factorial(n) = {  1 if n = 0, n*factorial(n-1) otherwise.
```

The loop *includes* the final value of *n*, so you get the full expression of the function (if you didn't, your answer would be off by a factor of *n* every time.

Comment: You're welcome.  You could always [upvote the answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) too, you know...

Answer (score 1):

You need i <= n because when you calculate factorial of 3! for example, you will have 
3! = 3 * 2 * 1 <=> 1 * 2 * 3

So, you have your n, that is 3 and the i is 1, then 2, then 3 (n).

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely you see that in loop for i take a values from 1 to n, so in i=n point for loop terminated. Loop for is created in this form to assure that factorial(0)=1. However, you can redesign this function in recursive style.